# Yii2 is possible run .bat file or python script

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

How to run python script in Yii2 framework? 
I try

```
$outputArr = shell_exec('python3 '.Yii::$app->basePath."/common/python/hello.py");
```

but it's not response

Thank you!

Comment: The `shell_exec` will work in yii framework exactly same way as it would work in clean php. If it's not working the problem is probably in server or php configuration.

Comment: try 
`$cmd = "python3 ".Yii::$app->basePath."/common/python/hello.py";`
`$output  = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd($cmd));`